# How can I use programmers dvorak layout on X11 apps on Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, xorg, keyboard-layout, dvorak, cygwin-x

How can I use programmers dvorak layout on X11 apps on Cygwin? Programers Dvorak works fine on my windows 10 host machine. However, when I type into X11 apps launched locally or remotely, I only get QWERTY.

How do I enable programers dvorak?

I tried -

```
user@host:~$ setxkbmap -v 10 -layout us -variant dvp -option compose:102 -option numpad:shift3 -option kpdl:semi -option keypad:atm -option caps:shift

Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to load rules file ./rules/base...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base...
Success.
Applied rules from base:
rules:      base
model:      macintosh
layout:     us
variant:    dvp
options:    compose:102,numpad:shift3,kpdl:semi,keypad:atm,caps:shift
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   macintosh+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete+numpad(mac)+caps(shift)+numpad(shift3)
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+macintosh_vndr/us(dvp)+inet(apple)+compose(102)+keypad(ops)+keypad(hex)+keypad(atm)+kpdl(semi)
geometry:   macintosh(macintosh)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

and got errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally discovered the problem.

`setxkbmap` loads my `-layout us` from the folder `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/macintosh_vndr/us` instead of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. The later file has the variant `dvp`, while the former does not.

You can check it using `cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us | grep -i dvp`.

I renamed the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/macintosh_vndr/us` and copied the file from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` to the `macintosh_vndr` folder and everything works fine. If someone can point a way how I can get the `setxkbmap` utility to read from the correct folder, I would use that approach.

The problem with my approach is that I have to re-do it every now and then when updates overwrite files in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb` folder